# Trying to prove inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I've been trying to prove the following inequality:

Given non-negative real numbers $A, B, C$ and $D$; If $A\leq C, \leq C$ and $A\cdot B \leq D\cdot C$ then $A+B \leq C+D$

I've tried many things, but couldn't see the proof. I'm afraid I might be missing or forgeting something obvious...

Comment: what is A.B? what is D.C?

Comment: $D\ge \frac{AB}{C}$. Then $C+D-(A+B)\ge C+\frac{AB}{C}-A-B$. See what you can get now.

Answer (score 1):

If $C=0$, so $A=B=0$ and our inequality is true.

Let $C>0$, $C-A=u$ and $C-B=v$.

Thus, $$(C-u)(C-v)\leq CD$$ or
$$D\geq\frac{(C-u)(C-v)}{C}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$C-u+C-v\leq C+\frac{(C-u)(C-v)}{C},$$ which is $$uv\geq0.$$